# Create slug-string from a title

Tags: php, regex

I try to get rid of some characters in a string. The string will be submited by a form (method: POST).
I need to get a lower case string. The Characters ä, ö, ü and ß should become ae, oe, ue and ss. All other special characters and whitespaces should be removed.

The string

```
Lorem_ipsum_Ö-ß    &änyOther char
```

should become

```
lorem-ipsum-oe-ss-aenyother-char
```

This is my code:

```
$slug = strtolower($_POST['title']);
$slug = trim($slug, '-');
$slug = preg_replace('/ä/g', 'ae', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/ö/g', 'oe', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/ü/g', 'üe', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/ß/g', 'ss', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/[^\w ]/g', '', $slug);
$slug = preg_replace('/ +/g', '-', $slug);
```

First of all, my attempt doesn't work as I want to.

And second: How can I make this code smaller? I guess it is possible to get this in just one regular expression...

Comment: Please explain "does not work"

Comment: I don't get a result.

Comment: no `/g` modifier for `preg_match`, remove it, will work fine.

Comment: Oh. Quite simple :-) Thanks.

Comment: `Ö` will not transform to lowercase using strtolower()

Comment: You are right. So do I have to add three more lines for Ä, Ö and Ü?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a function to do this. You can tweak this to your needs, here is an example.

```
function _replace($t) {
   $map = array( 'Ä' => 'ae', 'ä' => 'ae', 'ß' => 'ss', 'Ö' => 'oe', 
                 'ö' => 'oe', 'Ü' => 'ue', 'ü' => 'ue' );
   $slug = strtr(strtolower(trim($t)), $map);
   return preg_replace('~[\W_]+~', '-', $slug);
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/190398)</kbd>

Comment: Just one note to this: In my opinion you should use regex when you have to use regex. Otherwise it makes your code senselessly complicated. I honestly **don't** think that this is a use-case for a regex.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `/g` modifier for `preg_match`. You can use `preg_match_all` or you can just remove it.

[Here's your eval.in](https://eval.in/190332)

Conversely, if you're just looking to make cleaner URL's out of this and you're trying ot minimize the code into a 1-liner, we could use `iconv` with `TRANSLIT` to translate the charset to the closest charset of our choosing, such as UTF-8, then you could wrap it all up into a 1 liner.

```
$slug = strtolower(urlencode(preg_replace('/[\s\-]/', '', iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT',$str))));
```

[Here's the eval.in for this example](https://eval.in/190397)

Comment: Is it possible to optimize the code? Or do I have to take eight single lines?